# Why does a tunnel work by my server my remote url doesnt when connecting to socket.io

Tags: react-native, socket.io, expo, adb

I am finishing up a react native / expo app I have been workin on for 4 months. I am currently using an android emulator and socket.io. For some reason the only time the web socket works if I forward it to the remote server URL using ngrok. But if i directly put the server url it doesn't. Here is an example.

```
useEffect(()=> {

        const socket = io('https://536b-96-246-65.ngrok.io');
    //https://536b-96-246-65.ngrok.io forwards to example.com:3000

    },[]);

useEffect(()=> {

        const socket = io('https://example.com:3000');
    //not working

    },[]);
```

Comment: If the forwarded connection works but the direct connection fails it may be because of TLS certificate problems (assuming ngrok ignores TLS problems). Has the target web server a valid HTTPS certificate? Is the DNS name you use for accessing the server included in the server certificate?

Comment: @Robert What do you mean does it have a valid certifcate?

Comment: @Robert I am using a free certificate by whm

Comment: @Robert Yes you wherre right. The SSL certificate wasn't valid. I purchased a valid SSL from a company and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I was using a free SSL cert signed by cPanel. After purchasing a SSL from sectigo it worked!